# How can I see my compiler errors/warnings in Android Studio 3.01?

Tags: android-studio

In my program, I'm trying to send an http get request. I have a lot of errors, but I don't know where specifically they occur. How do I open the compiler error window? And is this different than the typical debugging in Android Studio where you set a breakpoint in your code?

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Usually, I use "messages" tab to see the compile errors that can be accessed using the Alt+0 shortcut. I also recommend you read the "Event log" too.
But if you want to read run time execution errors, you can open the "Logcat" tab or Alt+6. 
Attention, do not confuse compile errors (syntax errors) with run time executions errors (semantic errors, request errors, etc).